# Help me find the equation of this graph

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I would like to know the solution, and if possible the procedure of this question below;

I was given 2 functions: sin(x) and (1/x^2 +1).

I was also given the graph shown below.

The question is: using those 2 functions and manipulating them obtain the graph that was given to me.

Thank you for your time!

[image of the graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcUbH.png)

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: Your graph does not correspond to your expressions.  The wiggles come from $\sin(x)$ but the envelope has too flat a top, falls too quickly, and stays too close to $0$ for $\frac 1{1+x^2}$.  I do not understand what the question is.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Mr. Ross Millikan.   The question is to find a correspondent equation to this graph I showed using sin(x) * (1/(x^2 +1)). It's supposed to work manipulating the values of x, at least according to my professor.

Comment: @Francisco Pacheco. I cannot understand the meaning of what you wrote : a correspondent equation to this graph I showed using sin(x) * (1/(x^2 +1)). A graph showed using the function sin(x) * (1/(x^2 +1)).is very different from your graph. Please, rewrite entirely your question to clarify (not in comment but in re-editing the question, please) .

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear enough. I have tried to explain it better this time in my most recent edit. @JJacquelin

Answer (score 1):

$\sin(x)$ is convenient but not $\frac{1}{x^2+1}$. One have to adjust a function with some parameters. For example :

[image]

This is a rough approximate. For better fitting the parameters should be computed with a non-linear regression method. Instead of the even function  $\frac{1}{x^2+1}$ one could try other functions for example  of the logistic kind addapted to be even. But it seems that the OP want a function of the kind of polynomial fraction.

Comment: Not bad at all (as usual) !

Comment: Thank you very much! That will help me a lot.